# How can I select the engine for portable Texmaker?

Tags: texlive, texmaker

I have a portable TexMaker in my memory.
Portable TexLive 2012 is installed on it too.
I want to make my documents with TexMaker using engine which in TexLive.

Comment: Once you have installed [Portable Texlive](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#tlportable), you just need to configure Texmaker.  If you are on windows, you can use `Texworks` from the `tl-tray-menu` icon, another alternative cross-platform editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For Windows Users

Click on `tl-tray-menu` as shown in [Portable Texlive](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-430004.2).

### For Linux Users

**Note**: You should have `wine` installed and configured.

For the sake of this discussion, assume that your `TeXLive` folder is named `TeXLive2012`.

### USB Configuration

If the following is your USB file configuration:

```
USB folder
   |______texmakerwin32usb
   |______TeXLive2012
```

then fire up your portable `TeXMaker` by clicking on `texmaker.exe` inside the `texmakerwin32usb` folder and then set up the drivers by clicking:

> Options > Configure Texmaker > Commands

### Configuring PDF Viewer

Use the built-in viewer of Texmaker. Alternatively, you can download a portable PDF viewer of your liking and save to your USB. Then in *PDF Viewer*, click on the folder icon to browse to the location of the portable PDF viewer in your USB. For PS, see how to install `ghostscript` in the answers in [Configuring portable TeXstudio to use MiKTeX portable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42940/configuring-portable-texstudio-to-use-miktex-portable/89589#89589)

### Configuring the Drivers

For each driver, click on the folder icons in the `Commands` configuration and browse to the location of the corresponding driver in the `TeXLive2012` `bin` folder.

You should get *something* like this.

```
LaTeX > "../TeXLive2012/bin/latex" -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
PdfLaTeX > "../TeXLive2012/bin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
Latexmk > "../TeXLive2012/bin/latexmk" -e "$pdflatex=q/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode/" -pdf %.tex
Bib(la)tex > "../TeXLive2012/bin/biber" %
Makeindex > "../TeXLive2012/bin/makeindex" %.idx
dvips > "../TeXLive2012/bin/dvips" -o %.ps %.dvi
Dvipdfm > "../TeXLive2012/bin/dvipdfm" %.dvi
ps2pdf > "../TeXLive2012/bin/ps2pdf" %.ps
metapost > "../TeXLive2012/bin/mpost" --interaction nonstopmode
```

### First Steps in Setting Up a Portable TeXLive for Linux

It's easiest to just download the `.iso` file and [mount it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164227/how-to-mount-an-iso-file).

3. Create `TeXLive2012` in your USB root folder.
4. `cd` to the mounted directory. Usually

   ```
   cd /media/username/TeXLive2012
   ```

   You can replace `username` by your actual `username`.
5. Type and enter

   ```
   perl install-tl -portable
   ```
6. Choose the directory by typing `D` then write the location of your USB:

   ```
   /media/username/usbname/TeXLive2012
   ```

   then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You can specify every directory this way if you like. But since USB's are slow drives, you can choose to install it on a writable folder, say in your desktop then copy and paste the folder into your USB. I find it faster this way.

For `Texmaker`, simply unzip the folder to your root USB folder.

After doing this, you should have the file structure we have above.

Comment: I have tried this with latest texmaker usb. Seems to not find the tex executables when I use a relative path i.e. ../texlive/2012/etc but finds it if I use absolute paths D:/texlive/2012/etc any thoughts as makes it useless on a portable tex install and I want to use texmaker.