# MikTeX and TeXStudio portables both unpacked to usb flash drive. Now What?

Tags: packages, miktex, texstudio

I downloaded the portable packages of MikTex and TeXStudio, and unpacked them onto usb flash drive.  I do not understand what to do next to configure the TeXstudio to use or work with the MikTeX.  I do not understand how to use the information in the documentation I found.

I have seen but really do not understand this:
[Configuring portable TeXstudio to use MiKTeX portable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42940/configuring-portable-texstudio-to-use-miktex-portable)

The files I started with are miktex-portable-2.9.4250.exe and texstudio251_win32-usb.zip.  The computer is with Windows XP s.p. 3, intel celeron 2.0 GHz processor; and since the portables listed easily fit on the usb flash drive, the space there is more than enough.

Now, what do I do so that I can start to learn to use these programs?  How exactly to make the configuring?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you unpack the `.zip` and run the MiKTeX installer so that all of the set up is done on the USB?

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Windows but I can set it up a MiKTeX Portable with `wine`.

My assumption is that you don't know what to do with the files that you downloaded. Here is the workthrough on how to copy them into your USB Device.

For setting up the drivers, see my (shameless plug) new answer in [Configuring portable TeXstudio to use MiKTeX portable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42940/configuring-portable-texstudio-to-use-miktex-portable). (I put the setting up of driver path part of the answer there since that part is duplicated in the OP's question there.)

Here is the tutorial.

### MiKTeX Portable Installation

The installation of MiKTeX Portable (currently version 2.9.4250 Windows 32-Bit)  is summarized in the [download page](http://miktex.org/portable). Here are the steps for extracting MiKTeX Portable. The italicized instructions were copied from the download page.

1. *Create a new folder on the portable storage device.* You can name the file **MikTexPortable** as in [Configuring portable TeXstudio to use MiKTeX portable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42940/configuring-portable-texstudio-to-use-miktex-portable). *This folder becomes the installation directory.*
2. *Start the self-extractor* by double-clicking on `miktex-portable-2.9.4250.exe`.
3. *Click the ellipse button (the one with the three dots) and browse to the installation directory.* Suppose your USB drive is `E:` Then browse to `E:\MiKTeXPortable`.
4. Click the Extract button.

Your USB structure should now be like

```
USB Drive
   |
   |-MikTexPortable
```

### TeXStudio Portable Installation

Simply unzip the folder TeXStudio into the root folder or unzip it in any folder and copy the unzipped folder into the root folder of your USB device--it is where you are in when you have just opened your USB device. Your USB file structure should now look like

```
USB Drive
   |
   |-MikTexPortable
   |-TeXStudio
```

Then follow the procedures in the answers in [Configuring portable TeXStudio to use MiKTeX portable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42940/configuring-portable-texstudio-to-use-miktex-portable)

Comment: IMHO, mentioning the minimum usb drive size requirements for MiKTeX portable and TeXlive portable would help others and the peformance of a low drive space .