# glossaries texstudio and miktex portable

Tags: miktex, glossaries, texstudio

I am not quite sure if this question is on the right sx site but since it is heavily tex related I figured I ask here.

My setup consists of a windows machine with `texstudio` and `miktex`, both in the `portable` version. I am trying to use the `glossaries` package.

To do so I  want to run `makeglossaries` by means of a custom user command. However when I try this it complains about not finding `makeindex` on the path. However i added `miktex`'s bin folder to the *user*-path variable and if i type `makeindex` from a commandprompt outside miktexs bin folder it works just fine.

---

**What is the proper way of using `makeglossaries(.bat)` with the portable `miktex/texstudio` setup?**

---

Edit: I expiremented with changing the command line.
If I supply the `-d` `option to makeglossaries`, which sets the path in which to run `makeindex`, i can get it to *find* `makeindex`, however, this causes several further issues: I need to supply absolute paths for the index style with `-s`, and absolute paths to the temporary files, which then can't be written due to [miktexs security](http://masterthesis.schoenemann.biz/latex-miktex-2-9-und-makeindex/) feature.

Answer (score 2):

I have no TeXStudio and MiKTeX in portable version so I can't check it, but

- I know, that you can use a local TeXMF tree for your index style file.  Then MiKTeX is able to find it without knowing the complete path (see question [create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex) how to create an local TeXMF tree).
- Do you know question [configuring-portable-texstudio-to-use-miktex-portable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42940/configuring-portable-texstudio-to-use-miktex-portable)?
- Do you know question [relative-paths-with-texstudio-under-windows-portable-installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121122/relative-paths-with-texstudio-under-windows-portable-installation)?

Comment: I think this would have been better as a comment. Now to the questions you reference: 1) I do not want to use a custom index style file, since glossaries comes as a package and everything else is found besides the sty file to format the finished glossary I do not see how a custom tree helps if most parts of the package are found (including makeglossaries). 2) I managed to confiugre all other tools with relative paths, also it finds makeglossaries, but makeglossaries does not find makeindex in turn 3) see 2), I can manage with the relative paths `"../Miktex/miktex/bin/makeglossaries.exe"`

Comment: I do not mean to be offensive but the path to `makeglossaries` works, however `makeglossaries` fails to find `makeindex` if called from tex studio. I appreciate your effort, but I think in case of a link collection which can be partly found in the `Related` bar, you should use comments because if I would find my solution there it would be a duplicate/bad question.

Comment: I got Texstudio to run `makeglossaries` from the menu. However `makeglossaries` complained that it could not find `makeindex`, eventhough I put it on the `PATH` thus I supplied the path to `makeindex` to `makeglossaries` with the `-d` option, which in turn gave the error that the style file was not found, so I supplied the path to the stylefile with the `-s` option which lead to a nother error that the file could not be written. I put a link explaining the last issue in the question and explained all this in the question. currently i run makeglossaries from the shell.