# How to run TeXStudio on a PC?

Tags: miktex, texstudio

I have already downloaded MiKTeX and TeXStudio and I would like to know how to run them.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! So you have downloaded them, but did you install them (MikTeX first, then TeXStudio)? Because if you installed both, you could run TeX Studio from the Start Menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per TeXnician comment above you need to have installed in the best order. If you installed TeXstudio first its best to re-install it, **after** you update MiKTeX. For guidance with `MiKTeX` installation (including system-wide distribution) see [current user manual & FAQs](https://docs.miktex.org) NOTE **the installation manual STRONGLY advises a single user install** (To be clear. If you are a super user **just install as 1 user**, if you have 2 or more users then chose if its easier for 2 single users to update, rather than having to update 3 or more times (once as administrator plus yourself as user plus all the other system-wide users.)

If you are  trying to install in a portable fashion, **I recommend you do a standard install first** to check how it works, then for portable installation guidance see [configuring portable texstudio-to-use-miktex portable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42940/configuring-portable-texstudio-to-use-miktex-portable)

For help with `TeXstudio` installation (in English only) see [user manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html)

When you start-up TeXstudio it recognise the installed MiKTeX and make some alterations to work with it. Once TeXstudio is running you can usually use the menu Help > User Manual (in my case I can not since its blocked by browser security settings) so I use the user manual link above.